# How to access hashmap values from payload in dataweave 2.0?

Tags: hashmap, dataweave, linkedhashmap

payload is in a hashmap form in the following structure:

```
{
 key1_list=[ {key1.1= value, key1.2=value}, {key1.1= value, key1.2=value}],

 key2=value2,

 key3=value3,

 key4=value4

}
```

---

I need to access and store key1.1 to a variable

Answer (score 4):

Just use `payload.key1_list[0]."key1.1"` quotes are needed as key1.1 has a dot in the name.